# Wordpress/WooCommerce - list of products has 'duplicate' in the item popup menu twice

Tags: wordpress

It has been like this for years through many upgrades, but not i am getting around to tidying things up, so it is not part of a new release.

This is the hover menu from a product on the products list page.

```
ID: 296 | Edit | Quick Edit | Bin | View | Duplicate | Duplicate
```

The first duplicate links to:

```
wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product&ithemes-sync-duplicate-post-id=296
```

The second duplicate links to:

```
wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product&action=duplicate_product&post=296&_wpnonce=5c680bfa4a
```

I am sure the first should be suppressed by something in some code somewhere... but for whatever reason it ain't happening on my setup...

Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot and should not give links into your admin!

Comment: You have 2 products with ids: 287, 296. If I understand correct all you need is remove one of them

Comment: Hi, I am sure anyone could guess the links (but I do use a password manager so logging in is tough to crack!), however you are right that I shouldn't be so obvious, so I have edited the links - cheers

I pasted the second link from the wrong product(oops), the id is the same in both, I have edited the question... However I just got lucky and found the conflicting plugins (I spent hours on this in the past... this time it just popped up!)

Comment: Your admin is not accessible - links are dead.
Please notice that one comes from edit.php and the other from post-new.php.
I cannot guess what are you doing in there. Sorry

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but got lucky and found the problem... I have just posted my next problem, and it is a real nasty one! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54259177/wordpress-woocommerce-blank-new-post-admin-page-cant-create-posts

Answer (score 0):

I feel pretty stupid answering this myself so quickly when people have started looking at it for me... But I spent hours on this in the past and expected to spend more hours on it, but got lucky this time!

The second 'duplicate' is added by a pluging called 'iThemes' (its a service that allows central admin of multiple wordpress sites). I will contact them.