# Wordpress/Woocommerce - blank 'new post' admin page, can't create posts

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have had the store for years, but never added blog posts, so I am not sure how long this has been broken - it may have been from the very first version.

I am now looking at adding a blog to the store but selected 'new post' just gives a blank screen - the console in chrome shows the following errors.

```
> JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
data.min.js?ver=4.2.0:1 Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at Module.308 (data.min.js?ver=4.2.0:1)
    at r (data.min.js?ver=4.2.0:1)
    at wp.data.0 (data.min.js?ver=4.2.0:1)
    at data.min.js?ver=4.2.0:1
post-new.php:2018 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
    at post-new.php:2018
    at post-new.php:2020
```

The code is so abstracted that I am not sure what it is actually doing - but all the code is in wp-includes/js/dist/

And the bit of code throwing the error looks like this (the second line is highlighted as failing).

```
      var A = {
        reducer: Object(f.flowRight)([S("reducerKey"), S("selectorName")])(function() {
            var t = arguments.length > 0 && void 0 !== arguments[0] ? arguments[0] : new m.a
              , e = arguments.length > 1 ? arguments[1] : void 0;
            switch (e.type) {
            case "START_RESOLUTION":
            case "FINISH_RESOLUTION":
                var r = "START_RESOLUTION" === e.type
                  , n = new m.a(t);
                return n.set(e.args, r),
                n;
            case "INVALIDATE_RESOLUTION":
                var o = new m.a(t);
                return o.delete(e.args),
                o
            }
            return t
        }),
```

I have tried this in chrome and edge, both get exactly the same result - same error, but a bit less informative in the edge console.

Comment: Please add php debug info as well. You can see instructions in https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

And modify ```wp-config.php``` as described in section: Example wp-config.php for Debugging

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a guttenburg/block editor issue, the old classic editor, can be enabled using this plug in

https://wordpress.org/plugins/classic-editor/